# Getting "unknown error" while enabling caller id in Truecaller

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Am not able to enable live caller id in **Truecaller** . I tried reinstalling the app and am getting the same error. Please help me ASAP.

My phone is 820 , running on 14936.1000 build.

[image]

Comment: The app must be installed in phone memory for the function to work. Is the app installed in phone memory?

Comment: yes, the app is installed in internal memory! my default path to install app has always been internal. i tried reinstalling 3-4 times too.

Comment: After you cancel this Close popup. Does it(Show Who is calling) remain on or off.
If its off call customer care to get it resolved and if its on then check by calling on your phone. See if its working (Showing callerID). I believe this Unknown Error! could be for some other cause.

Comment: it doesn't show who's calling, but when i go to the app, i can see who called me.

Comment: Have you  tried enabling enhanced search option?

Comment: please update the Truecaller app to the new 4.2 version.

Comment: I would recommend to ignore this issue as truecaller has not yet developed stable version of their application for windows phone. As this issue has been reported from several window phone models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HIT AND TRIAL

820:
1. Go to Security > Auto start > Enable Truecaller
2. Go to Security > Permissions > Permissions > Truecaller > Display pop-up window > Accept
3. Go to Notifications > Manage Notifications > Truecaller > Show Floating Notifications

820:
For 820:  Phone Settings > Additional Settings > Battery > Manage apps battery usage > Choose apps > Truecaller > Custom and in Background Network , choose stay connected.

Alternative solution, Phone settings > security > permissions > truecaller > allow all permissions. After that, go to additional settings > battery > manage apps battery usuage, by default its "standard" make sure to keep it off,

820:
Battery settings > Manage background data